# Creating nested dynamic components in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I Want to know how to create nested dynamic components and maintains its parent child relationship.

For example, I have data like this,

```
- A
--A.1
--A.2
-B
--B.1
-C
```

I wanted to create the component like this,

```
<A>
   <A1></A1>
   <A2></A2>
</A>
<B>
   <B1></B1>
</B>
<C></C>
```

But with my code I could only create parent component or child component. But not both.

Below is my code,

```
  setRootViewContainerRef(view: ViewContainerRef): void {
    this.rootViewContainer = view;
  }

  createComponent(content: any, type: any) {
 console.log(content);
    if (content.child && content.child.length > 0) {
      content.child.forEach(type => {
        const typeP = this.contentMappings[type.type];
        this.createComponent(type, typeP);
      });
    } else {
      this.renderComp(content,type)
    }
  }

  renderComp(content,type) {
    if (!type) {
      return
    }
    this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
    this.componentReference = this.rootViewContainer.createComponent(this.componentFactory);

    if (this.componentReference.instance.contentOnCreate) {
      this.componentReference.instance.contentOnCreate(content);
    }
  }
```

With this code, I get this output.

Link to working example, [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-lcxpwm?file=src/app/create-dynamic-component.service.ts)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

---

Updated.

Even after adding the `viewChild`, It still throws the `viewchild not defined`.

Refer this image, In the component.instance I'm not seeing the view child element.

[image]

Updated stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-mepwch?file=src/app/content/a/a.component.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create ViewContainer on each level that is going to render child components:

**a.component.html**

```
<p>
a works!
</p>
<ng-container #container></ng-container>
```

**a.component.ts**

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) embeddedContainer: ViewContainerRef;
```

And then render component to dedicated container:

**create-dynamic-component.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CreateDynamicComponentService {
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    @Inject(CONTENT_MAPPINGS) private contentMappings: any,
    private inlineService: InlineService
  ) { }


  createComponent(content: any, type: any, vcRef) {
    const componentRef = this.renderComp(content, type, vcRef)
    if (content.child && content.child.length) {
      if (!componentRef.instance.embeddedContainer) {
        const cmpName = componentRef.instance.constructor.name;
        throw new TypeError(`Trying to render embedded content. ${cmpName} must have @ViewChild() embeddedContainer defined`);
      }

       content.child.forEach(type => {
        const typeP = this.contentMappings[type.type];
        this.createComponent(type, typeP, componentRef.instance.embeddedContainer);
      });
    }
  }

  renderComp(content,type, vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
    const componentRef = vcRef.createComponent<any>(componentFactory);

    if (componentRef.instance.contentOnCreate) {
      componentRef.instance.contentOnCreate(content);
    }

    return componentRef;
  }
}
```

Note how `renderComp` method takes `ViewContainerRef` from the component with children:

```
 this.createComponent(type, typeP, componentRef.instance.embeddedContainer);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-j7v3za?file=src/app/content/a/a.component.ts)**

Comment: It's not working in Angular v8. I get this error `Property 'instance' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Looks like you forgot something. Try this version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-tbz6kx?file=src/app/create-dynamic-component.service.ts

Comment: As you said I've added the viewChild in A comp also updated the html, But in console it shows that `must have @ViewChild() embeddedContainer defined`.

Comment: Have you tried my example? Did you see I defined `<ng-container #container></ng-container>` in AComponent? If it gives you that error then it means that component doesn't have container defined

Comment: Yes I've defined. For for some reason `emmbededComponent` is not coming in instance.  I've added like this in A comp ` @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef,  static: false }) embeddedContainer: ViewContainerRef;` and in html `<ng-container #container></ng-container>`

Comment: Please reproduce it in stackblitz

Comment: I replicated the issue, Please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-mepwch?file=src/app/content/a/a.component.ts

Comment: `@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef,  static: true })` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-new-j7v3za?file=src/app/content/a/a.component.ts

Comment: Yes. Worked Thanks. You saved my day

Comment: @yurzui Great answer. You should update it with what's in your comment: the "static: true" part.